# How to convert Greater metropolitan area name to country in r?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a big dataset of location where some names have metropolitan name and others have countries. I was able to use `separate` to separate out the location to different parts, but there are some cases where the location only have country name or "Greater Stockholm Metropolitan Area" or "Greater Colorado Area". I'd like those to be get the country name from it too and store in the appropriate column. How can I do that?

Here's what I have tried.

```
df <- df %>% separate(location, c("locale", "state", "country"), sep = ",", extra = "merge", fill = "right")
```

which then resulted the following dataframe.

```
structure(list(location = c("Höllviksnäs, Skåne County, Sweden", 
"Helsingborg, Skåne County, Sweden", "London, England, United Kingdom", 
"Scottsdale, Arizona, United States", "Seattle, Washington, United States", 
"Charleston, South Carolina, United States", "United States", 
"New York, New York, United States", "Basel, Basel, Switzerland", 
"Kuala Lumpur, Federal Territory of Kuala Lumpur, Malaysia", 
"Atlanta, Georgia, United States", "Edmonton, Alberta, Canada", 
"Antony, Île-de-France, France", "Israel", "Essex, Ontario, Canada", 
"Burlingame, California, United States", "Chattanooga, Tennessee, United States", 
"Marlborough, England, United Kingdom", "Greater Stockholm Metropolitan Area", 
"Sacramento, California, United States", "Laguna Beach, California, United States", 
"Greater Chicago Area", "United States", "Greater Minneapolis-St. Paul Area", 
"El Paso, Texas, United States"), locale = c("Höllviksnäs", 
"Helsingborg", "London", "Scottsdale", "Seattle", "Charleston", 
"United States", "New York", "Basel", "Kuala Lumpur", "Atlanta", 
"Edmonton", "Antony", "Israel", "Essex", "Burlingame", "Chattanooga", 
"Marlborough", "Greater Stockholm Metropolitan Area", "Sacramento", 
"Laguna Beach", "Greater Chicago Area", "United States", "Greater Minneapolis-St. Paul Area", 
"El Paso"), state = c(" Skåne County", " Skåne County", " England", 
" Arizona", " Washington", " South Carolina", NA, " New York", 
" Basel", " Federal Territory of Kuala Lumpur", " Georgia", " Alberta", 
" Île-de-France", NA, " Ontario", " California", " Tennessee", 
" England", NA, " California", " California", NA, NA, NA, " Texas"
), country = c(" Sweden", " Sweden", " United Kingdom", " United States", 
" United States", " United States", NA, " United States", " Switzerland", 
" Malaysia", " United States", " Canada", " France", NA, " Canada", 
" United States", " United States", " United Kingdom", NA, " United States", 
" United States", NA, NA, NA, " United States")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -25L))
```

Comment: You'll need to do it manually, using `case_match` (the "new" `recode`). Anyway, I cannot see what you've tried. Just your data.

Comment: To automate this, you would need to find some way of looking up which country a particular metropolitan area was in and matching it. There is certainly nothing built in to R that would know that "Greater Stockholm Metropolitan Area" should map to "Sweden". The code would be fairly straightforward if you can find such a resource.

Comment: @AllanCameron, I'm trying `countrycode` package. Combining with @harre response, I'll use these two and see if it works. I'll post my resolution.